# How can I obtain a member function pointer to the copy constructor of a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, copy-constructor, pointer-to-member

Is there any way to get a member function pointer to the copy constructor of a class? I know how to define and use a normal member function pointer, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get it.

Comment: You cannot. Constructors do not have names.

Comment: You can't but depending on what you want to do, you might be able to find a workaround using a lamda. I.e. putting it in the lamda.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Suppose you somehow  managed to obtain a pointer to a constructor (not that you can) - how would you use it? What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Makaronodentro - minor point, but it's spelled "lambda", not "lamda".

Comment: @rubenvb Why do you need it? With the advent of lambdas the practice passing of member functions has largely gone the way of the record player. It's likely that there is a better way to approach your problem.

Comment: if you could, how would you plan to use it? I.e the syntax for mfp is `(someObject.*mfp)(args)`. how would you use the copy constructor member function pointer to construct a new object with that syntax?

Comment: @Johannes right, I'm asking the wrong question. I just need a copiable `default_copy` class that prevents slicing that I can use in my `value_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++ standard, "the address of a constructor shall not be taken," so it's just not possible to do what you're asking. However, there's a simple workaround. The below code returns a function pointer to a function that creates a copy of it's input.

```
template<class obj> auto GetCopyConstructor() -> obj(*)(const obj&) 
{
    return +[](const obj& o) { return obj(o); };
}    
struct foo
{
    std::string msg;
    foo(const std::string& my_msg) { msg = my_msg; }
    foo(const foo&) = default;
};
int main()
{
    auto make_copy = GetCopyConstructor<foo>();
    foo a("Hello, world");
    foo b = make_copy(a);
    std::cout << b.msg << std::endl;
}
```

**Alternatively:** (A simplification that also covers additional use cases)

```
template<class obj> obj Copy(const obj& o) { return obj(o); }
template<class obj> obj* CopyNew(const obj& o) { return new obj(o); }
template<class obj> obj CopyFromPtr(const obj* o) { return obj(*o); }
template<class obj> obj* CopyNewFromPtr(const obj* o) { return new obj(*o); }
template<class obj> void* WhyWouldYouEvenWantToDoThis(const void* o) 
{ return new obj(*(obj*)o); }
int main()
{
    foo(*make_copy)(const foo&) = Copy<foo>;
    foo a("Hello, world");
    foo b = make_copy(a);
    std::cout << b.msg << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The only missing lines are #include <iostream> and #include <string>, and the code works in both C++11 and C++14 using the GCC compiler. What problems are you having?

Comment: [Never mind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this). Learned something new today.

Comment: The + should not be necessary, not sure why it's there? It should trigger an implicit conversion upon return just fine without it.

Comment: @NirFriedman the `+` would be relevant if the trailing return type were omitted (in which case the return type is deduced from the argument of the return statement, without applying the conversion of lambda to function-pointer)

Comment: Hmm this would be fine if I could store the results of different GetCopyConstructor calls in one type. I guess making the return type `void*(*)(void*)` would do, but also sidestep the type system :(

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: I added more code; hopefully some of it will be useful.

Comment: You might also mention that, even aside from explicitly not being able to take their addresses, constructors and destructors are not technically functions!

Comment: What I was trying to do was this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40330151/256138. You did point me in the right direction. Note I am not convinced the final construct is useful. I'm quite sure it's not useless though ;).